# How long does the `pthread_t*` argument to `pthread_create` need to survive?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, lifetime

The signature of `pthread_create(3)` is:

```
   int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

What are the requirements on the storage duration of the `pthread_t *thread` argument? The man page for `pthread_create` says:

> Before  returning,  a successful call to `pthread_create()` stores the ID of the new thread in the buffer pointed to by `thread`;

But it's not clear if it means that it stores the value there so that the caller can examine it, or if it uses that buffer to store the value (implying that the buffer needs to stay usable for the whole lifetime of the child thread).

Similarly, `pthread_self` says it returns

> the same value that is returned in `*thread` in the `pthread_create(3)` call that created this thread.

but it's not clear if it means that it returns *the value stored in `*thread`* or *a value equal to what was returned in `*thread`*.

Concretely, I'm wondering if it's legal to have something like:

```
void make_thread(void) {
  pthread_t tid;
  return pthread_create(&tid, NULL, some_fn, NULL);
}
```

or if `tid` needs to be `malloc`'d. When I put `tid` on the stack, I get a bunch of errors in valgrind related to `_Unwind_ForcedUnwind`, which makes me suspect that `*thread` needs to remain valid for the lifetime of the child thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thread ID is returned for your own use. You don't need to store it if you're going to detach the thread or the thread is going to detach itself.

```
void make_thread(void) {
  pthread_t tid;
  return pthread_create(&tid, NULL, some_fn, NULL);
}
```

This is kind of odd. You can't join the thread, because you didn't keep its ID. And you didn't detach it. I suppose this could be fine if the thread detaches itself, but that's an odd way to do things.

Comment: Maybe you can actually pass NULL as the argument, if you don't need the id.

Comment: I tried to find out in the man pages if NULL was an acceptable argument, but it's not clear:(

Comment: @MartinJames it looks like passing `NULL` causes a segfault, for reasons that are unclear (if you're just passing it back to me in case I want it, why do you ask me to allocate storage for it?). It looks like my `_Unwind_ForcedUnwind` errors are from a different source, anyway.

Comment: Passing `NULL` for the first parameter is not allowed. It's kind of an odd choice, but it is what it is.